# Bypass all rules and redirect internally to another folder/file

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, configuration

In Apache config file, there are some rules defines like below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteRule   ^(Category)/([^/]+)/(.+)$     index.php?module=$1&id=$2&action=$3   [B,L,QSA]
  RewriteRule   ^(Listing)/(.+)$              index.php?module=$1&id=$2             [B,L,QSA]
  RewriteRule   ^([^/]+)/(.+)$                index.php?module=$1&action=$2         [B,L,QSA]
  ...
</IfModule>
```

All this address `http://web/foo/bar` is *internally* translated (no redirects) into `http://web/index.php?module=foo&id=bar`: `foo`, `bar` are fed to index.php as params.

Now I want to add a rule which translates `http://web/api?key1=val1&key2=val2` to `http://web/api/index.php?key1=val1&key2=val2` in a similar manner.

I tried placing `RewriteRule   ^(api)//?(.+)$   api/index.php?$2  [B,L,QSA]` at top of all rules, restarted apache but `http://web/api?foo=bar` becomes `http://web/api/?foo=bar` (with extra `/` after `api`) in browser's address bar and the call is redirected to `http://web/index.php` (as it throws error from the file).

How to change the RewriteRule to render `http://web/api/index.php` when request is made `http://web/api?..`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have a `api` directory.    The Apache code that handles redirects to add slashes to the directory is happening before the rewrite rule.   Move your api directory to something else (like `apiscripts`) and then use the rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule   ^api$ apiscripts/index.php [L,QSA]
```

You need the flags on the rewrite rule:

- `L` (last) -- so that other rules don't also get triggered
- `QSA` (query string append) -- so that mod_rewrite passes the parameters through

I would also recommend adding some conditions to your last rewrite rule to ensure that it isn't triggered for any paths that actually represent directories, files, or links:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)$ index.php?module=$1&action=$2 [B,L,QSA]
```

Comment: I renamed `api` directory to `apachescripts`, but it is still giving 404 with that rule you mentioned.

Comment: I forgot to mention (don't know if it makes a difference), the web root is `http://web/site/` and apiscripts are located `http://web/site/apachescripts/index.php`. The default index is located at `http://web/site/index.php`.